# Is Windows Media Player able to play DTS audio?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No DTS Audio output in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/210796/no-dts-audio-output-in-windows-7)

I'm trying to play *DTS* audio with **Windows Media Player 12 on Windows 7.**

For a *MPEG-TS* file with video and *DTS* audio, only video is played.
A file containing only a DTS audio stream is rejected.

But: WMP is able to play the DTS audio stream of a DVD.

**So, Is Windows Media Player able to play DTS audio, or not?** And if: How do I make him play my DTS files?

I did not find any good resources of the supported codecs. Just things like *"WMP can play .mpg files, ..."*

*VLC is able to play all of the above files.*
*I do not want to install third party codec packs, thats not the question!*

Answer (score 0):

Directly, 'out of the box', no, it is not possible.
A codec is required for windows to understand DTS.

this is one codec I found to allow DTS to be played: [ac3filter](http://ac3filter.net/wiki/Projects/ac3filter)

Comment: I can play DVDs with DTS sound fine in WMP, without any third party codec.

Comment: the Audio part of the DVD-Video codec is contained within that codec. I don't know of a way to separate the two